# Google Analytics User-ID | Value for singed out users

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I integrated the Google Analytics User-ID feature on our website today (in combination with Google Tag Manager). It's working great for logged in users.

I use the UID of our system for logged in users.

[Logged in user example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGI0O.png)

However, I am not sure which value has to be used for users that are **not logged in.**

Currently, it's just blank if the `userId` value can not be set because the user is not logged in yet.

[Logged out user example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFi99.png)

Is it okay if its just blank? Or do I have to set the value to something specific?

I thought about:

- setting a Default Value for the Data Layer Variable for `userId` in the GTM
- using the `clientId` that is stored in the `_ga` cookie

But I just don't know which what the correct thing to do is here. I can't find a clear answer to this online, and the Google Guides and Documentations don't expressively say anything about it either that I've seen.

I would really appreciate any help with this. And thank you in advance for your suggestions and answers!

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a user is logged out, you should just totally skip pushing the `userId` onto the dataLayer. In this case, the GTM `userId` variable will resolve to `undefined` (because it will not find such a key on the dataLayer) and Google Analytics will ignore it altogether and the `&uid` query parameter will not be sent to GA.

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry I didn't see your answer until now! I will implement it like that! :)

Comment: not sure, but stop pushing userId to GTM shouldnt stop it. Once userId is set, it will remain till the end of a session, am I wrong?